# How to handle HTTP basic Authentication on selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a problem on my automation testing on selenium using C#. My application use the IP address as a base URL and use HTTP authentication alert message as a login. Then my features i test on my application is the LAN features i need to change the IP address so every time i change the IP address it ask me again the authentication for that application. My Code i use is like this:

On the first run of my application i call this code and it works, it inputs the user name and password on the HTTP Auth textbox.

```
 SendKeys.SendWait("user");
 SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
 SendKeys.SendWait("pass");
 SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

Then after i call the method for changing the IP, then call this code again.

```
 SendKeys.SendWait("user");
 SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
 SendKeys.SendWait("pass");
 SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

It's not work anymore, it show me the pop up but not input the user and password. How can i still used that code after i change my IP?

Comment: focus on the pop up, is it?

Comment: Yes focus on the pop up and input the user and password on the pop up textbox. I create on first instance but after second call it's not working anymore

Comment: Could you post the the block of code. thanks

Comment: This is my block of code:
   public void TestMethod1()
        {
        DriverContext.Driver.Navigate().GotURL("URL");
        // My login first call it works
         SendKeys.SendWait("admin");
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait("admin");
            SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");

            ChangingIP(); // Method for changing IP
           // After changing IP HTTP Auth appears again
           i input again the Login using Sendkeys.SendwWait but it's not working anymore nothing happens

}

Answer (score 0):

Insert a delay in the beginning of the method.

`using System.Threading.Tasks
...
Task.Delay(5000).Wait();`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but i already do that and it's not working